# How to build and install and use Crypto++ 8.6.0 in windows 10 with CLion?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw-w64, crypto++

I am trying to use Crypto++ 8.6.0 for my use in my project, but I cannot use the library. I have tried to use [these](https://www.babaei.net/blog/how-to-build-cpp-cryptographic-library-cryptopp/) instructions at first to build Crypto++ with qmake, but it did not work. Then, I decided to use the MinGW option from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/ievgensychov/cryptopp) but it is outdated and cannot be applied to 8.6.0
I have successfully created a cryptopp-static.lib file using CMake files in [this](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-cmake) repo, then I moved the file to my project root folder where CMakeLists.txt and added

```
target_link_libraries(MyApp cryptopp-static.lib)
```

after `add_executable`
but it returned an error

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.2.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\MyApp\cmake-build-release --target MyApp -- -j 6
[ 25%] Linking CXX executable MyApp.exe
C:/MinGW/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcryptopp-static
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\MyApp.dir\build.make:124: MyApp.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/MyApp.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:89: CMakeFiles/MyApp.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:123: MyApp] Error 2
```

I have also tried just running `make` on the source directory of Crypto++, because it has a GNUMakefile, and in return I got `libcryptopp.a`, I moved this file to the root directory of my project and cmake, but it returned the same error as above.

Then I tried to add this to my CMakeLists.txt as said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library) question.

```
add_library(CryptoPP STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(CryptoPP PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /cryptopp-static.lib)
target_link_libraries(MyApp cryptopp-static.lib)
```

But it still returned the same error.

Is there any easy way I can build, install, and use Crypto++ 8.6.0 in Windows 10 with CLion?

Comment: did you build cryptopp with mingw? When you got `libcryptopp.a` were you still trying to link to `cryptopp-static.lib` rather than `libcryptopp.a`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles i ran `make` in the source directory to get libcryptopp.a. When I got it i replaced cryptopp-static.lib with libcryptopp.a but it returned the same error.